# VB.NET Constantly polling a directory for files is causing an ongoing increase in memory usage

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a small application that on startup instantiates a class, reads in a JSON array from a text file and builds an object.  It then initialises a new `system.timers.timer` and scans a directory every xx minute(s) to get a file count.

When my application starts up, Windows Task Manager shows it at around 13MB of Memory, however, leaving it to run for about 12 hours now shows it at 700+MB of Memory when no files were even detected in this directory.  I'm worried that this is just going to grow forever and eventually crash.  It doesn't seem like anything is getting cleaned up by the `GC` (probably because my timer and objects are always active).

Although this class is quite simple in theory, I do have other functions and timers involved that don't get called until required.  I am happy to post all my code somewhere, or even just the class, but it's a little too long to add to this post.

I have included the main elements of my class however:

```
Public Sub Initialize()
        Try
            If AgentSettings.DebugMode Then CreateLog("Entered Module: Initialize()")



            CreateLog("Initializing Alerting Rule: <" & Me.Name & ">")
            CreateLog("Validating all Rule Profiles")



            'Loop through all the Rule Profiles and make sure they are all valid
            'If not, disable the profile so it never scans
            For Each profile As RuleProfile In Me.RuleProfiles



                CreateLog("Verifying Profile: <" & profile.Name & ">")



                'Check to make sure the Profile is functionally valid
                If ProfileIsValid(profile) Then



                    'Profile is valid so setup an event handler to handle the isBroken event
                    profile.Active = True
                    CreateLog("Rule Profile: <" & profile.Name & "> Enabled")
                    AddHandler profile.BrokenStatusChanged, AddressOf CheckIfRuleIsBroken



                Else



                    'Disable the Profile
                    CreateLog("Rule Profile: <" & profile.Name & "> Disabled")
                    profile.Active = False



                End If



            Next



            'Setup the checking timer and set the interval to the default checking time
            If Me.ruleCheckTimer Is Nothing Then



                Me.ruleCheckTimer = New System.Timers.Timer
                Me.ruleCheckTimer.AutoReset = True
                Me.ruleCheckTimer.Interval = Me.DefaultMinutesToCheck * 60000
                AddHandler Me.ruleCheckTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf CheckRule



            End If


            'If there is an escalation plan then setup a timer for it
            If Me.EscalationPlan.PlanItems.Count > 0 Then



                'Setup the escalation timer and set the interval to the first plan item
                If Me.escalationTimer Is Nothing Then



                    Me.escalationTimer = New System.Timers.Timer
                    Me.escalationTimer.AutoReset = True
                    AddHandler Me.escalationTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf Escalate



                End If



            End If



        Catch ex As Exception
            CreateLog("Module: Initialize()" & vbNewLine & "Exception Error: " & ex.Message)


        End Try
    End Sub


Private Sub CheckRule(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Try
            If AgentSettings.DebugMode Then CreateLog("Entered Module: CheckRule()")



            'Loop through all the profiles
            For Each profile As RuleProfile In Me.RuleProfiles



                CreateLog("Scanning for active profiles")



                'Make sure the Profile is active
                If profile.Active Then



                    Select Case profile.Name



                        Case "FileCount"



                            CreateLog("Checking Rule Profile: <" & profile.Name & "> for isBroken status")



                            'Get file count of the specified directory
                            Dim files As String()
                            files = Directory.GetFiles(profile.DirectoryPath)



                            'Determine if we're checking for files greater than or less than
                            If profile.GreaterThan Then



                                If files.Count > profile.FileCount Then



                                    profile.isBroken = True



                                Else



                                    profile.isBroken = False



                                End If



                            Else



                                If files.Count < profile.FileCount Then



                                    profile.isBroken = True



                                Else



                                    profile.isBroken = False



                                End If



                            End If



                            files = Nothing



                    End Select



                End If



            Next



        Catch ex As Exception
            CreateLog("Module: CheckRule()" & vbNewLine & "Exception Error: " & ex.Message)


        End Try
    End Sub
```

When `profile.isBroken` receives an update, it triggers an event which then loops through all profiles to determine which ones are broken.  If all are broken, then it begins its alerting and escalation process.  However, none of this is occurring and my memory is still increasing constantly.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?  Or maybe a better way (and more efficient way) of polling this directory?

The theory behind my application is to instantiate multiple classes to allow various directories or files to be scanned, but if the memory has increased this much with just the one instance, I'm concerned about running multiple.

**EDITED**

My log handling is as follows:

```
Public Sub CreateLog(ByVal text As String)
    Try
        'Create Log Directory if it doesn't exist
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) & "\MyCompany\Agent\Log")) Then System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) & "\MyCompany\Agent\Log\")



        'Write log entry
        LogFile = GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) & "\MyCompany\Agent\Log\" & "Logfile - " & Format(Now, "ddMMyyyy") & ".txt"
        File.AppendAllText(LogFile, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & "  " & text & Environment.NewLine)



        'Update the activity text on the main UI
        frmMain.UpdateActivityText(text)



    Catch ex As Exception
        'No need to create a log entry


    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Visual Studio comes with Code Analysis and Profiler tools to track this sort of thing down

Comment: Why use a `Timer` at all?  Why not use a `FileSystemWatcher` to receive notifications when the folder changes?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I had thought of that, however, I wanted to create the class so it will monitor all various types of scenarios.  Files, folders, processes, resources, etc.  Therefore, everything flows through the exact same code whether it be a file check or a disk space check.

Comment: Can you post your `CreateLog` function. I'd start looking there since it is handling strings

Comment: @Plutonix Thankyou for your recommendation regarding the Code Analysis.  That helped me identify a number of unknown issues I had sitting in my code behind the scenes.  Making the required changes as per the report and detecting a possible issue in the `CreateLog` function (thanks to SSS for the heads up) seems to have fixed my memory creep.

Comment: Depending on your edition/version there may be static and runtime profilers available.  There is also one that analyzes code and gives all sorts of complexity and maintainability metrics